# Where clause match to variable not working

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Good Day!
I have this query:

```
$name = $this->input->get_post('name');
$unit = $this->input->get_post('unit');
$user = $this->session->userdata('user');
$sql = $this->db->query("select ID from type WHERE code LIKE '%".$unit."%'");
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
$this->db->set('Name', $name);
$this->db->set('Unit', $result);
$this->db->set('Owner', $user);
$this->db->set('CreatedBy', $user);
$this->db->set('ModifiedBy', $user);
$this->db->insert('prod');
$this->db->select('ID');
$this->db->from('type');
$this->db->where('%'.$unit.'% = type.code');

$id = $this->db->insert_id();

return (isset($id)) ? $id : FALSE;
```

I don't know why I can't set the table `Unit` with a value of `ID` from the table `type` when I have a condition in where clause.

Can someone help me?

Comment: what framework? codeigniter? And did you mean set the column `Unit` with the value of `type.code`, because if `Unit` is a table then you have it all wrong.

Comment: Yes, codeigniter. Set the Unit with the value of column ID from the table type when $outputunit is equals to the value of column Code from the table Type.

Comment: you can us like instead of where

Comment: It still not working. I edited the code above and put the select query into a variable. But still not working.:(

Comment: @user3326074: can you please post your error?

Comment: and the error query as well?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the code is trying to accomplish, but `like()` doesn't require the % to be included.  If you call `like('type.code', '%1234%')` the query will have `WHERE type.code LIKE '%\%1234\%%'`.  So you can just write `$this->db->like('type.code', $unit);`  If you wanted the % only on one side or you wanted to be explicit, `like()` takes a third argument which can be `'both'`, `'before'`, `'after'`, or`'none'` to specify where to insert %.

That may not be your only error:

```
$sql = $this->db->query("select ID from type WHERE code LIKE '%".$unit."%'");
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

[The documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/database/results.html) says that `$sql` in the above code would be a result object, and calling `mysql_query()` on it would have unpredictable results.  To get the actual result object, you should call either `$sql->result()` (if you expect to get more than one row) or just `$sql->row()` since it seems like you're looking for only one row.

```
$this->db->set('Unit', $result);
```

Here, you want to use `$result->ID` (assuming `$result` is the row and not an array of rows).  Setting Unit to `$result` isn't going to work.  Either it'll set Unit to 0 or some other unintentional value stemming from the fact that `$result` is a `stdClass` object, not a scalar value.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Rename the "type" table something like code_type and see what if it works.